# UnicodeDecodeError while iterating over MongoDB collection

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am trying to query a MongoDB database using Python 2.7 and pymongo-2.3 using something like this:

```
from pymongo import Connection

connection = Connection()
db = connection['db-name']
collections = db.subName
entries = collections['collection-name']
print entries 
# > Collection(Database(Connection('localhost', 27017), u'db-name'), u'subName.collection-name')

for entry in entries.find():
    pass
```

The iterator fails even though I don't do anything with the `entry` objects:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/../mongo.py", line 27, in <module>
  for entry in entries.find():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 778, in next
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 742, in _refresh
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pymongo/cursor.py", line 686, in __send_message
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/pymongo/helpers.py", line 111, in _unpack_response
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 744: invalid start byte
```

I'm not the creator of the database I'm trying to query.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thanks.

---

**Update**: I managed to skip over the offending line from `pymongo/helpers.py` using a `try-except`, but I would prefer a solution that does not involve data loss.

```
try:
    result["data"] = bson.decode_all(response[20:], as_class, tz_aware, uuid_subtype)
except:
    result["data"] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the same operation using the mongo shell? I want to figure out if it's something Python-specific or if it's corruption in the database:

```
$ mongo db-name  
> var collection = db.getCollection('subName.collection-name')  
> collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { printjson(doc); })
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Tried `collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {print("1");})` for speed, and there were no errors. It seems it's Python-related.

Comment: OK, can you do, in Python, `for entry in entries.find().sort([('_id', 1)]): print entry['_id']`? That'll give you the _id just before the problematic document. Then take that _id and in the shell, `collection.findOne({_id: {$gt: my_id}})` and post that here.

Comment: Surprisingly this now fails in the console (also in Python): `collection.findOne({_id: {$gt: ObjectId("4ebcd5f0ed7c5031a103ba68")}})` I don't know why I didn't catch this the first time I tried. `decode failed. probably invalid utf-8 string` -- bunch of garbage -- `why: TypeError: UTF-8 character 0x1234567 too large
src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1018`

Comment: Definitely corruption in Mongo's own datafiles. Did you experience a crash or unclean shutdown, or do you see errors in the mongod logfile? Can you try shutting down, making a backup of the data files, restarting with --repair?: http://es.wiki.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair