# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 2

Tags: python, mongodb, python-unicode

I had written a source code to derive performance of stocks. It is running in an instance efficiently but showing "UnicodeDecodeError" while running in my local. I reffered this [python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23772144/python-unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc0-in-position-0-i), but still I am confusing about how it works in an instance without error and how can I solve it? I would highly appreciate if you coud answer me with a solution since I am new to this encode and decode stuff in python.

Following is the function in which the error occurs

```
def CollectFromDate(eb_grade, year, month):
    global monthly_days, end_date
    start_date = datetime.strptime('%s%s01' % (year, '0%s' % month if month<10 else month) , '%Y%m%d')
    No_days = monthrange(year, month)[1]
    end_date = datetime.strptime('%s%s%s' % (year,  '0%s' % month if month<10 else month, No_days) , '%Y%m%d')
    monthly_days = [(start_date+timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for i in range(No_days)]
    MemBackup = db.memcache_backup.find({'_id' : {'$in': monthly_days}})
    ScripFrom = {}
    for DATA in MemBackup:
        date = DATA.pop('_id')
        for scrip, val in DATA.items():
            valuation = val['pro_valuation_average']['result']
            if valuation in ['Strong Upside', 'Upside'] and val['eb_score'][1] in eb_grade and scrip not in ScripFrom:
                ScripFrom[scrip] = [{'from': date, 'from_val': valuation}]
    return ScripFrom
```

and following is the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/faizalmohammed/Mvc-EB/lib/excellent_companies.py", line 201, in <module>
    pprint (ProcessPerformanceData(eb_grade, year, month))
  File "/Users/faizalmohammed/Mvc-EB/lib/excellent_companies.py", line 79, in ProcessPerformanceData
    ScripPerform = CollectFromDate(eb_grade, year, month)
  File "/Users/faizalmohammed/Mvc-EB/lib/excellent_companies.py", line 176, in CollectFromDate
    for DATA in MemBackup:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 814, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 776, in _refresh
    limit, self.__id))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 720, in __send_message
    self.__uuid_subtype)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 112, in _unpack_response
    as_class, tz_aware, uuid_subtype)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 2: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12727692/821594

Comment: @martijn-pieters code lines were very helpfull to understand the traceback output, why delete them?

Comment: @stalk: the line numbers are entirely redundant here, it is patently clear what line from the sample is affected. And line numbers make it harder to copy the code and paste it into an editor or live session to try and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @stalk: on balance, they do more harm than good.

Comment: so, it is the problem with my mongodb collection?

Comment: @ManikandanV, do you have same behaviour, as in mentioned question?

Comment: @stalk, Can you give me a propper solution rather than restore the Collection?